# Navigator pass arguments with pushNamed

Tags: flutter

Might have been asked before but I can't find it but how do you pass a arguments to a named route?

This is how I build my routes

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Navigator(
      initialRoute: 'home/chooseroom',
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        WidgetBuilder builder;
        switch (settings.name) {
          case 'home/chooseroom':
            // navigates to 'signup/choose_credentials'.
            builder = (BuildContext _) => new ChoosePage();
            break;
          case 'home/createpage':
            builder = (BuildContext _) => new CreateRoomPage();
            break;
          case 'home/presentation':
            builder = (BuildContext _) => new Presentation();
            break;
          default:
            throw new Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
        }
        return new MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
      },
    );
```

This is how you call it
`Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('home/presentation')`

But what if my widget is `new Presentation(arg1, arg2, arg3)`?

Comment: looks like it isn't supported out of the box : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6225

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`pushNamed()` now supports arguments as of this [merged pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/27058). If you can't wait, switch to channel `master` (`flutter channel master` and probably followed by `flutter upgrade`).

How to **send**:

```
    Navigator.pushNamed(ctx, '/foo', arguments: someObject);
```

How to **receive**:

```
...
    return MaterialApp(
        ...
        onGenerateRoute: _getRoute,
        ...
    );
...

Route<dynamic> _getRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    if (settings.name == '/foo') {
        // FooRoute constructor expects SomeObject
        return _buildRoute(settings, new FooRoute(settings.arguments));
    }

    return null;
}

MaterialPageRoute _buildRoute(RouteSettings settings, Widget builder) {
    return new MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (ctx) => builder,
    );
}
```

The "arguments" can be any object, e.g. a map.

Comment: Can you please explain what FooRoute is meant to be?

Comment: @UndercoverCoder `FooRoute` is the 2nd/target screen.

Comment: for some reason my arguments arent going through as a map.  always null

Comment: the settings argument in MaterialPageRoute is Important, without this, you can not get the correct argument when using it.

Answer (score 139):

No need for `onGenerateRoute`. Simply use

```
var exampleArgument = 'example string';

Navigator.pushNamed(
    context,
    '/otherscreen',
    arguments: {'exampleArgument': exampleArgument},
);
```

and extract the arguments as follows:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final arguments = (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments ?? <String, dynamic>{}) as Map;

    print(arguments['exampleArgument']);

    return Scaffold(...);
}
```

Comment: for calling back the argument, i should write like this : 
**text(arguments['path'])** **text(arguments['path2'])** **text(arguments['path3'])** ? 
And it's possible to stored the arguments in variable so i just calling something like this **loadedArgument.path**,**loadedArgument.path2**,**loadedArgument.path3** ?

Comment: @ZeffryReynando
 Yes, you can acess any argument by using its key name like `arguments['first']`, `arguments['second']` etc. according to `arguments: {'first': 43, 'second': true}`. For your second question just wrap the arguments in a class, which allows you to use a point for accessing field members.

Comment: What if in the initState() I need the passed argument for an api call ? context is yet not available there. How to solve this? thx

Comment: @cwhisperer You can try using 
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {doContextStuff(context);
}); in initState()

Comment: final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map;    this give a error which is type null is not a subtype of type map in type cast i dont know why .

Comment: @Adnanhaider I had the  same problem. I think the code in this answer assumes the settings.arguments can't be null. Which in my case it could. So `as Map` was trying to convert null to a Map, which results in an error. I got around this first by removing `as Map` from that line and also adding a null check `final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments;`.  Then `if (arguments != null) ` you can convert arguments to a Map.

Comment: Working it with this via `RouteSettigns` .
`final arguments = (settings.arguments ?? <String, dynamic>{}) as Map;`

Answer (score 14):

It took me a while to notice this, as I'm a newbie to Flutter. But the arguments you add using `Navigator.pushNamed` get sent directly to the widget you pushed NOT the MaterialApp for routing.

So in widget you push a new screen from you'll have:

```dart
Navigator.pushNamed(
   context,
   SomePage.routeName,
   arguments: {
      'v1': 'data1',
      'v2': 'data2',
      'v3': 'data3',
   },
)
```

You won't need those arguments in your constructor at all. Instead your pull them out in the SomePage widget like the others are saying; namely via:

```dart
final arg = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
```

and can assign them within SomePage build like:

```dart
randomVar1 = arg['v1'];
randomVar2 = arg['v2'];
randomVar3 = arg['v3'];
```

using whatever keys you put in.

if you want MaterialApp to handle it then you use the [onGenerateRoute](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments#alternatively-extract-the-arguments-using-ongenerateroute) method. This took me forever to notice that the arguments go directly to the widget pushed. For me it was counter-intuitive.

Comment: Thanks. What function does `as Map` perform?

Comment: this function interpret your arguments as Map

Answer (score 9):

Arguments can be any object, you can make an array as you can see:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/upload', arguments: {'_imagePath':_imagePath,
      'num_docfiscal':num_docfiscal,'dta_docfiscal':dta_docfiscal});
```

and access to the router class.

Comment: this is a map, not an array

Answer (score 7):

Basically you have 2 options :

- Use some 3rd party package for routing - I think the best is **[Fluro](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/fluro)** .
- exploit `onGenerateRoute` . This option is limited to args you can pass (string/numbers)

To use second option, assuming you want to pass three arguments: `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('home/presentation:arg1:1337:hello')`

```
MaterialApp ( 
         ... ,
         onGenerateRoute: handleRoute,
         routes:... , ) 

Route<dynamic> handleRoute(RouteSettings settings) {

    WidgetBuilder builder;

    final List<String> uri = settings.name.split('/');

    if (uri[0].startsWith('home')) {

      // handle all home routes:
      if(uri[1].startsWith('presentation:'){
         // cut slice by slice
         final String allArgs = 
               uri[1].substring('presentation:'.length);
         final List<String> args = allArgs.split(':');

          // use your string args
         print(args[0]);             // prints "arg1"
         int x = int.parse(args[1]); // becomes 1337
         print(args[2]);             // prints "hello"

         builder = (ctx)=> Presentation(args[0],args[1],args[2]);
...
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the fast reply, but if I can pass in a string I can still pass in a json string if I want to send objects to my presentation widget?

Comment: It's possible, but i believe it would be a better approach to save objects somewhere, ( i prefer redux store)   and pass minimal needed amount of data ( id )  via router,  then fetch objects from store using id inside your page. This way will be more future-proof

Answer (score 6):

For simple navigation with arguments from WidgetA to WidgetB

1. Define routes in MaterialApp main widget:

```dart
    return MaterialApp(
       routes: {
           '/routeAB': (context) => WidgetB(),
       },
```

2. In WidgetA use pushNamed method to navigate to WidgetB:

```dart
  onTap: () { 
     Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/routeAB', 
       arguments: {
          'arg1': val1,
          'arg2': val2,
          ...
```

3. Get arguments in WidgetB:

```dart
    Map args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

Comment: type null is not a subtype of type map in type cast,   error i got

Answer (score 2):

*Note*: [new routing options may be available soon](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q0jx0l4-xymph9O6zLaOY4d_f7YFpNWX_eGbzYxr9wY/edit#heading=h.2gvb5wtr8clk).

---

Could this be a possible option?

> Use `push` with a `RouteSettings` argument specifying the named route.

This way you can directly pass arguments of any type (including objects) to your destination Widget in a type safe manner and skip using `arguments`.  You won't need to [create a single-use throwaway arguments class](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments) nor a Map.

`RouteSettings` in `push` can supply a named `Route` to your Navigation stack which you can search for / use in future routing decisions, just the same as if you had used `pushNamed`.

### Push + RouteSettings

To use `push` with a named route, use `RouteSettings` argument with the route name.

Example: a user logs in on `Page1` and now you want `push` them from `Page1` to `Page2`

Directly inside `Page1` pass the `User` object (`loggedInUser`) to `Page2` within a `Navigator.push` call and use a `RouteSettings` arg with your route name (`/page2`).

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => Page2(user: loggedInUser),
  settings: RouteSettings(name: '/page2')
));
```

And in Page2 widget, you can expect and use the `User` object directly.

```
class Page2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final User loggedInUser;

  Page2(this.loggedInUser);

  @override
  _Page2State createState() => _Page2State();
}

class _Page2State extends State<Page2> {
  User loggedInUser;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loggedInUser = widget.loggedInUser;
    print(loggedInUser.name);
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  }
}
```

Later on you can use `/page2` route name.  For example if you're at `/page3` and you want to `popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/page2'))`, this allows that.

### Under the Hood

Flutter's `Navigator` class shows `pushNamed` uses `push` + [`routeNamed`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart#L3350)  and `routeNamed` uses  `RouteSettings`.

```
Future<T> pushNamed<T extends Object>(
    String routeName, {
    Object arguments,
  }) {
    return push<T>(_routeNamed<T>(routeName, arguments: arguments));
  }
```

```
Route<T> _routeNamed<T>(String name, { @required Object arguments, bool allowNull = false }) {
final RouteSettings settings = RouteSettings(
      name: name,
      arguments: arguments,
    );
    Route<T> route = widget.onGenerateRoute(settings) as Route<T>;
return route;
```

Comment: TOP!! The best solution for me thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pass arguments:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(YourScreen.routeName, arguments: {"title":myTitle, "user_name":userName});
```

Extract arguments:

```
        Map<String, dynamic> arguments = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(settings.arguments);
        page = MyRecordingScreen(title: arguments["title"], tags: arguments["user_name"], );
```

Answer (score 1):

For `named Routes` with multiple arguments or dynamic object you need to do as follow(this is MVVM pattern example):

navigator:

```
void navigateEditParty(int index) {
    _navigationService.navigateTo(PartyEditRoute,
        arguments: {"hunter": hunter, "index": index});
  }
```

router:

```
case PartyEditRoute:
  Map args = settings.arguments;
  return _getPageRoute(
    routeName: settings.name,
    viewToShow: PartyEditView(
      hunter: args["hunter"],
      index: args["index"],
    ),
  );
```

class:

```
PartyEditView({Key key, this.hunter, this.index}) : super(key: key);
```

Comment: How does MVVM apply here? Without any code for _navigationService or _getPageRoute, I'm having trouble understanding your answer

Answer (score 0):

It is always best to wrap your arguments in an object to avoid error prone code.

Below are the working example on how you can achieve it in flutter dart.

To send

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(Routes.submitSuccess, arguments: successModel);
```

To Receive

```
  case Routes.submitSuccess:
    if (settings.arguments is SubmitSuccessModel) {//Check for instance here
      return CupertinoPageRoute(
          builder: (_) =>
              SubmitSuccessPage(successModel: settings.arguments));
    }
```

Model Object

```
class SubmitSuccessModel {
  SubmitSuccessModel(
      {this.title, this.desc, this.actionButtonName, this.widget});
  String title;
  String desc;
  String actionButtonName;
  Widget widget;
}

final SubmitSuccessModel successModel = SubmitSuccessModel(
  title: 'Title',
  desc: 'Desc',
  actionButtonName: 'Done',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to notice this, as I'm a newbie to Flutter. But the arguments you add using `Navigator.pushNamed` get sent directly to the widget you pushed NOT the MaterialApp for routing.

You don't need those arguments in your constructor at all. Instead your pull them out in the widget like the others are saying; namely via:

```dart
final arg = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
```

and can assign them like:

```dart
randomVar1 = arg['v1'];
randomVar2 = arg['v2'];
randomVar3 = arg['v3'];
```

using whatever keys you put in.

if you want MaterialApp to handle it then you use the [onGenerateRoute](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments#alternatively-extract-the-arguments-using-ongenerateroute) method. This took me forever to notice that the arguments go directly to the widget pushed. For me it was counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

screeen_1.dart

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/screen2',arguments: {'var1': val1 ,'var2': val2, "var3": val3 ,"var4" : val4}); //sending of the values to route_generator.dart
```

route_generator.dart

```
class RouteGenerator {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) //from screeen_1.dart
{
    // Getting arguments passed in while calling Navigator.pushNamed
    Map args = settings.arguments;

switch (settings.name) {
case '/screen2':
        if (args is Map) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => screen_2(args),
          );
        }
        return _errorRoute(); //optional written in a scaffold when any error arrises
default:
return _errorRoute(); //optional written in a scaffold when any error arrises

}
```

screen_2.dart

```
screen_2(Map args) //follow the params from the route_generator.dart
{
  return Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _screen_2EndpointProvider.fetchScreen_2(args['var1'], args["var2"], args['var3'], args['var4']),  //API call inside which it called the args 
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return snapshot.hasData
              ? screen_2(param: snapshot.data)
              : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }),
  );
}
```

I tried to provide a simple example, if it could be helpful to anyone, because i was  facing the same error after a lots of trials it got solved.

Answer (score 0):

*After a long day fighting with the routes and onGeneratedRoutes on how i should pass the data and retrieve i finally understand it here is what i learned about*

**routes:** - the property of MaterialApp

```
routes: {'/profile': (context) => const Profile()}

onTap () {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profile', arguments: {'name': 'someone'});
};
```

**On the profile Screen**

```
  final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Map;
```

don't forget do Downcast to the right data type using the as keyword.

**useGeneratedRoute:** - the property of MaterialApp for dynamic routes

```
onGenerateRoute: Routes.RouteGenerator,
```

on Routes class

```
static Route<dynamic> generateR(RouteSettings settings) {
    
    switch (settings.name) {
        final args = settings.arguments;
        case 'profile':
          if (args is Map) {
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => Profile(
                  title: args,
              ));
          }
    default:
      return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: ((context) => const NotFound()));
  }
```

}

on class Profile create a constructor and a field of type Map or whatever you what to pass as data.

```
 final Map<String> data;

 const Profile({
     super.key,
     required this.data,
  });
```

and you can now use the data as you wish.

```
child: const Text(data[name]);
```

So use the best option for your context i struggle so much to understand because i was get the null error. hope it's help you need

Answer (score 0):

That's how to send parameters / arguments-

```
ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => NewPresentation(
                                      id: '101',
                                      name: 'Unnamed',
                                    )));
                      },
                      child: const Text('Submit'))
```

And that's how to receive -

```
class NewPresentation extends StatefulWidget {
  final String id, name;
  
  const NewPresentation({Key? key, required this.id, required this.name}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<NewPresentation> createState() => _NewPresentationState();
}

class _NewPresentationState extends State<NewPresentation> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.id + widget.name);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Screen 1 :

```
Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
    settings: RouteSettings(arguments: e),
    builder: (context) =>
    const AnnouncementDetail()),
);
```

screen 2 :

```
//get parameters
final arg = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Announcement;

Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const Text('Anang', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            Text('Diposting pada ${DateFormat("d MMMM yyyy", "id_ID")
                .format(DateTime.parse('${arg.announcementDate!} 00:00:00.000'))}', style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Text(arg.announcementTitle!, style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),),
            const SizedBox(height: 16),
            Html(
                style : {
                  "body": Style(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                    margin: Margins(
                      bottom: Margin.zero(),
                      left: Margin.zero(),
                      top: Margin.zero(),
                      right: Margin.zero(),
                    )
                  )
                },
                data: arg.announcement)
          ],
        )
```

Announcement.dart

```
class Announcement {
  Announcement({
      this.id, 
      this.announcementDate, 
      this.announcementTitle, 
      this.announcement, 
      this.month, 
      this.createdBy, 
      this.createdAt, 
      this.updatedAt,});

  Announcement.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    id = json['id'];
    announcementDate = json['announcement_date'];
    announcementTitle = json['announcement_title'];
    announcement = json['announcement'];
    month = json['month'];
    createdBy = json['created_by'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }
  int? id;
  String? announcementDate;
  String? announcementTitle;
  String? announcement;
  String? month;
  int? createdBy;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['id'] = id;
    map['announcement_date'] = announcementDate;
    map['announcement_title'] = announcementTitle;
    map['announcement'] = announcement;
    map['month'] = month;
    map['created_by'] = createdBy;
    map['created_at'] = createdAt;
    map['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    return map;
  }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

// Main Screen from where we want to Navigate

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
                              context,
                             "/ScreenName",
                              arguments: {
                                'id': "20" 
                              });
```

I also faced the same issue I was using NavigationRoutes

```
class NavigationRoutes {
  static Route<dynamic> generateScreenRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
   // TODO below we are able to get Arguments list
    Map args = settings.arguments;
    
    switch (settings.name) {
      
      case "Screen Name": 
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenName(args)); 
      // TODO pass above argument here and get in the form of Constructor in Screen 
      //   Name Class
    }

}
```