# How to pass a value parameter in ChildModule of Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to push param value(index and user_name) from User_Management_Page to User_Detail_page via Navigator.pushNamed. But I can't know a way to do this.
In User_Management_Page:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/user-management/detail',
  arguments: {index, user.name},
 );
```

Set up RouterModule:

```
 @override
 // TODO: implement routers
  List<Router> get routers => [
    Router("/usermagement", child: (_, args) => UsersPage()),
    Router("/detail", child: (_, args) => UserDetailPage()),
  ];
```

And the contractor class User_detail:

```
class UserDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
      final int index;
      final String name;

      UserDetailPage({Key key, this.index, this.name}) : super(key: key);
    }
```

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments please see this once it may help u :)

or u may go with this also https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770709/8388068

Answer (score 0):

This solution is very easy by passing variables in constructor:

first page:

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>SecondPage('something')));
```

second page:

```
class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
 String something;
 SecondPage(this.something);

 @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
   return SecondPageState(this.something);
  }
}



class SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
 String something;
 SecondPageState(this.something);

 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
   //now you have passing variable
    title: Text(something),
    ),
  ...
  }
```

Comment: must be `final String something;`

Comment: Thank you, but I must use Navigator.pushNamed() for this case