# How to receive arguments from pushNamed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I've changed my Navigator.push to `Navigator.pushNamed` but I don't understand how to pass data and receive/use it. If we use `Navigator.push`, we can just do this and call the constructor to use the data, but if we use `Navigator.pushNamed`, it sends arguments.
Now, how to call/use these arguments?

in /surveyPage page how do i call the arguments? in /surveyPage i have constructor languageCode but since I use pushNamed I cannot put languageCode.

This is the widget that I want to receive the argument, I want to pass the argument to languageCode

```
class SurveyConsentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SurveyConsentPage({this.languageCode, Key key}) : super(key: key);
  final String languageCode;
```

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => SurveyConsentPage(
      languageCode: 'id',
    ),
  ),
);
```

pushNamed

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/surveyPage', arguments: 'id');
```

routes

```
 case '/surveyPage':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SurveyConsentPage());
        break;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I navigate between 2 classes, one of them requires passing data? in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68605567/how-can-i-navigate-between-2-classes-one-of-them-requires-passing-data-in-flut)

Comment: thanks but it's not because i use pushNamed and arguments

Comment: Can you include your `routes`

Comment: This will probably help you: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigator pass arguments with pushNamed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53304340/navigator-pass-arguments-with-pushnamed)

Comment: there i add my routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your route case:

```
case '/surveyPage':
  final code = settings.arguments as String;
  return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SurveyConsentPage(languageCode: code));
  break;
```

Make sure you have defined `String languageCode` as a required parameter to your `SurveyConsentPage` widget.

```
class SurveyConsentPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String languageCode;
  SurveyConsentPage({required this.languageCode, Key key}) : super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass arguments

```dart
onPressed: () {
  final String id = "myId is X";
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/surveyPage', arguments: id);
},
```

And to receive arguments it is essential to check null value, also notice that I am passing `String` value, if you are using different data type replace it. A better approach is by creating class as shown on [cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final arguments = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String?;
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(arguments ?? "did not get any data"),
    ),
  );
}
```

You can remove `languageCode` variable from `SurveyConsentPage` widget and use `arguments`.