# Unable to pass arguments thro Navigator

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to pass arguments thro Navigator.pushNamed but i get this error

type 'RouteSettings' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

here is the Navigator

```
onTap: (){
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, "ProductDetScreen",arguments: ProductModelsvar.id);
          },
```

and this is where i get them in the second page

```
final productProviders = Provider.of<productProvider>(context);
final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings as String;
final getCurrentProduct=productProviders.findProductById(productId);
```

Comment: You should access the `arguments` property  `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments`

Answer (score 0):

the named routes should start with a `/'

when declaring the routes in the `routes` property in `MaterialApp` :

```
final Map<String, WidgetBuilder>? routes;
```

so you should declare routes like :

```
routes: {
"/ProductDetScreen": () => ProductDetScreen(),
// more routes
}
```

so you can use it inside your code like this :

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/ProductDetScreen",arguments: 
 ProductModelsvar.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure this `ProductModelsvar.id` also a `String`.

because you cast it as `String` here:

```
final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings as String;
```

official documantation : [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/passing-data#alternatively-pass-the-arguments-using-routesettings)

---

but better avoid use `!` for `null-safety` reason. use like below:

```
// set empty string if its null
final productId = (ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings ?? '') as String;
```

ref: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59174503/12838877)